# Polymorphic relationship ember data url endpoint calls confusion

Tags: ember.js

Hi I am trying to set up polymorphic relationship
user has one profile which can be admin, point_of_contact.

In the sessionAccount service mentioned below
on calling `user.get('profile')` my understanding is ember will smartly call `/pointOfContacts/1` but it is calling `/profiles/1`

//serializers/application.js

```
import { ActiveModelSerializer } from 'active-model-adapter';
export default ActiveModelSerializer.extend();
```

//adapters/application.js

```
import ActiveModelAdapter from 'active-model-adapter';
export default ActiveModelAdapter.extend();
```

//model.user.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
const {
  attr,
  belongsTo
}=DS;
export default DS.Model.extend({
  email: attr('string'),
  profile: belongsTo('profile',{polymorphic:true , async: true})
});
```

//model/profile.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
export default DS.Model.extend({

});
```

//model pointOfContact

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import Profile from './profile';
const {
  attr,
} = DS;
export default Profile.extend({
  firstName: attr('string'),
});
```

Since ember cli mirage does not support polymorphic relationships yet. 
my mirage config looks like this

```
 this.get('/users/:id',(schema,request)=>{
    let record = schema.db.users.find(request.params.id);
    let { id, email, token , profileId, profileType } = record;
    let profileTypeModel = pluralize(profileType);
    let profileRecord = schema.db[profileTypeModel].find(profileId);
    let userRecord = {  id:id,
        email:email,
        token:token,
        profile_id: profileId,
        profile_type: profileType
    };
    let formattedResponse = { user: userRecord };
    formattedResponse[profileTypeModel] = [profileRecord];

    return formattedResponse;
  });
```

so My json response to user/:id looks like this

```
{
  "user": {
    "id": "1",
    "email": "some@email.com",
    "profile_id": 1, // these two lines
    "profile_type": "pointOfContact" // tell Ember Data what the polymorphic
                            // relationship is.
  },
  "pointOfContacts": [{
    "id": 1,
    "firstName": "somefirstname"
  }]
}
```

Now I want to put this role into a sevice called sessionAccount. So that i can use it anywhere in application
I am using ember-simple-auth

```
import Ember from 'ember';
const {
  inject:{
    service
  },
  computed
} = Ember;

export default Ember.Service.extend({
  session: service(),
  store: service(),
  account: computed('session.data.authenticated.user.id',function(){
    const userId = this.get('session.data.authenticated.user.id');
    if(!Ember.isEmpty(userId)){
      return this.get('store').findRecord('user',userId).then((user)=>{
        return user.get('profile');
      });
    }
  })
});
```